# what is the use of servletcontainer initializer and how does this play a role in configuring servlets without web.xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, servlets

I am trying to configure spring app without web.xml,after googling i found webappintializer can do that, which internally uses servletcontainer initilizer,what is the use of servletcontainer initializer and how does this play a role in configuring servlets without web.xml

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do initialization when the application starts or clean up when it is destroyed, you should use this interface.

When the application starts, the Servlet container calls the OnStart method of this interface, passing in as a parameter a set of all classes that implement, extend or are annotated with the type(s) declared in the HandlesTypes annotation.

The specification also add a number of methods to dynamically register Servlets, filters and listeners.

Following is example how you initialize your spring dispatcher Servlet :

```
public class MyWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext ctx) throws ServletException {

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = ctx.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet());
        dispatcher .setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher .addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**WebApplicationInitializer** - This provides programmatic way of registering servlets to your Servlet Context. Prior to servlet 3.0, you can do it only through web.xml. With servlet 3.0 specification you can register your dispatcher servlet to the servlet context, so they will be aware of your application context and function similar to servlets registered in your web.xml.

**ServletContext** is nothing but that provide interface method to interact with your servlet container. Its Javadoc is pretty good.

**SpringServletContainerInitializer** which is an implementation of **ServletContainerInitializer** is responsible for invoking the onStartup of **WebApplicationInitializer** and passes it a ref to **ServletContext**.

Both **web.xml** and **WebApplicationInitializer** can coexist and you can register additional servlets and i think you can override servlets as well.

You have tons of example out there in web to show you how to use **WebApplicationInitializer**

Hope this helps.